# Adding "and" between last two database results in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I want to add the word "and" between the last two MySQL results. I can add commas but I need to add commas between the first ones and then "and" between the last two.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        $not_first = false;

        foreach($solos as $solo)
        {
            if ($not_first)
            {
                echo ', ';
            }
            $not_first = true;

            echo $solo->id;
        }
```

I could echo 'and' instead of the comma. But if I have 3 or more results it would say "result and result and result and result". I want it to say "result, result, result, and result".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use next idea

```
if (count($solos) > 2) {
    $last = array_pop($solos);
    echo implode(', ', $solos) . ' and ' . $last;
}
else
{
    echo implode(' and ', $solos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer using `for` instead of `foreach` in this case:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($solos); $i++){
    echo $solos[$i]->id;

    if($i == count($solos) - 2){        // --> second last element, implies "and" 
        echo " and ";
    }
    else{
        if($i != count($solos) - 1){    // --> "," for all other elements, except last
            echo ", ";
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
   $i = 1;
   $last = count($solos);
    foreach($solos as $solo)
    {
        if ($i > 1 && $i != $last)
        {
            echo ', ';
        }
        elseif ( $i == $last )
        {
            echo ' and ';
        }

        echo $solo->id;
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can count it and at second last id append "and" instead of ","

```
$x = count($solos);
foreach($solos as $solo){
    echo $solo->id;
    if ($solos[$x - 2] == $solo){
        echo 'and';
    }elseif ($solos[$x -1] != $solo && $solos[0] != $solo){
        echo ',' 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work perfectly. For the sake of completeness, you could also insert an "and" using preg_replace.

```
$solos = array( 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' );

$result = implode(', ',$solos);
$result = preg_replace('/, ([^,]+)$/',', and \1', $result);
```

Over 1 million iterations, *mnv's* array_pop method took 2.13 seconds. preg_replace completed in 3.65 seconds. Using array_pop would be preferable.